# How to check for first value in JSON object?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

Im getting returned json from an API and need to check the first object - which doesn't have a key / value - for jQuery ajax success function. Normally, with returned JSON like

```
{"type":"Return","FirstName":"test","LastName":"test"}
```

I can check like this

```
success: function(data){
        if(data.type == "Return"){
            //do stuff  
        } else {
            //failed
        }
}
```

How do I perform the same type of check, to see if the value is "tax" or "error" with an object like this?

```
{"tax":{"order_total_amount":1099.0,"shipping":0.0}}

success: function(data){
    if(data[0] == "tax"){
        //do stuff
    } else {
        //failed
    }
}
```

doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Here are the entire data objects.
Successful:

```
{"tax":{"order_total_amount":1099.0,"shipping":0.0,"taxable_amount":0.0,"amount_to_collect":0.0,"rate":0.0,"has_nexus":true,"freight_taxable":false,"tax_source":"destination","jurisdictions":{"country":"US","state":"CO","county":"ADAMS","city":"THORNTON"},"breakdown":{"taxable_amount":0.0,"tax_collectable":0.0,"combined_tax_rate":0.0,"state_taxable_amount":0.0,"state_tax_rate":0.0,"state_tax_collectable":0.0,"county_taxable_amount":0.0,"county_tax_rate":0.0,"county_tax_collectable":0.0,"city_taxable_amount":0.0,"city_tax_rate":0.0,"city_tax_collectable":0.0,"special_district_taxable_amount":0.0,"special_tax_rate":0.0,"special_district_tax_collectable":0.0,"line_items":[{"id":"1","taxable_amount":0.0,"tax_collectable":0.0,"combined_tax_rate":0.0,"state_taxable_amount":0.0,"state_sales_tax_rate":0.0,"state_amount":0.0,"county_taxable_amount":0.0,"county_tax_rate":0.0,"county_amount":0.0,"city_taxable_amount":0.0,"city_tax_rate":0.0,"city_amount":0.0,"special_district_taxable_amount":0.0,"special_tax_rate":0.0,"special_district_amount":0.0}]}}}
```

Error:

```
{"error":"Bad Request","detail":"to_zip 55478 is not used within to_state AL","status":400}
```

Comment: It's not the obvious typo in function() is it?

Comment: sorry fixed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty). For example:

```
success: function(data) {
    if(data.hasOwnProperty("tax")) {
        //do stuff
    } else {
        //failed
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. One follow up, what would you use to simply check if it is error in this object (regardless of error value) {"error":"Bad Request","detail":"to_zip 55478 is not used within to_state AL","status":400}

Comment: Well, I suppose you could do the same and check for `data.hasOwnProperty("error")`. All of this is assuming that you either have one or the other (and never both of them) in the same response.

Comment: I tried that, it only worked on the first case, didn't work with data.hasOwnProperty("error") - no alert was shown

Comment: Are you sure that was the entire `data` object in your previous comment?

Comment: Updated question with the complete responses for "tax" and "error"

Comment: It should definitely work. Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tajuh18e/

Comment: I must have had a typo - works as expected. Thank you!